# data structures sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

if we have n elements with keys:{0,1,-1} and we want to sort them,how many comparison at least we have in the worst case?

Comment: Sounds like homework. Also, you need to elaborate a bit on the problem.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "with keys {0, 1, -1}"?

Comment: when we want to sort cards with some keys,instead of sorting with their values we can sort them by keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that runs in O(n):

1. Create an array of three lists.
2. For each key/value entry, do

   ```
   lists[entry.key + 1].append(entry)
   ```
3. Concatenate the three lists into one long list.

This way you have no comparisons between keys.

Comment: You need to compare if an element = -1, 0, or else is 1. So 2n?

Comment: Ok, sure. ϑ(n) comparisons then. (But no comparisons between different keys.)

Answer (score 1):

With a small fixed number of possible values, you can sort in linear time with something like [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: how can i do that with a linear time?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the algorithm used and distribution of the of elements.

Comment: its about the lower bound of sorting and the decision tree model,

Comment: When he says "worst case" he probably means "worst case for best possible algorithm".